# Creating lists and sublists dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple little one page website for giving a presentation and I have some working code now, but I'm thinking there has to be a more elegant way of doing this. I would describe myself, at best, as a "dabbler" in JavaScript at this point; I'm much more comfortable with statically-typed languages and am doing this as a learning exercise.

Here's my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ECDZY/3/) showing what I am doing.

In my "real" site, the `PageContent` object is coming from an AJAX POST response (via an instance of node.js). I've included all of that code to make it easier to understand what is going on (any suggestions on how to restructure that server-side code would also be appreciated). If I have the time, I'll probably read these "points" from a config file or something else, but for now, a switch statement fits my needs.

The segment of this that makes me the most uneasy is this:

```
$('#pageContent').append('<li id="' + i + '">' + mp.main);
    if (mp.subPoints.length > 0){
        $('li#'+i).append('<ul>');
        $.each(mp.subPoints, function(index, sp){
            $('li#'+i+' ul').append('<li>' + sp + '</li>');
        });
        $('li#'+i).append('</ul>');
    }
    $('#pageContent').append('</li>');
```

I don't like how I am having to add `id` values to my list items so I can then append my subpoints to the correct parent. Is there a less hacky-feeling way to go about this?

In case it isn't obvious from the fiddle, the page should show a list of main points, and, if they exist, subpoints under each main point. I'm basically trying to mimic PowerPoint.

Any criticisms of this code would be gladly accepted; I know this probably isn't idiomatic JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on your content and how you prepare it, but I'd suggest a very generic solution that'll work for any level of nested points. Now, arbitrary nesting doesn't appear to be required in your case, but, hey, nice to have.

Suppose your JSON content is structured like so:

```
var points = [
    {title: "Point", children: [
        {title: "Point"},
        {title: "Point"},
        {title: "Point"},
        {title: "Point", children: [
            {title: "Point"},
            {title: "Point"},
            {title: "Point", children: [
              // more...?
            ]}
        ]}
    ]}
]
```

You'll note that you can just keep nesting the points indefinitely.

To render this as HTML, you can use a recursive function. Like this:

```
function buildList(parentElement, items) {
    var i, l, list, li;
    if( !items || !items.length ) { return; } // return here if there are no items to render
    list = $("<ul></ul>").appendTo(parentElement); // create a list element within the parent element
    for(i = 0, l = items.length ; i < l ; i++) {
        li = $("<li></li>").text(items[i].title);  // make a list item element
        buildList(li, items[i].children);          // add its subpoints
        list.append(li);
    }
}
```

And call it like so:

```
buildList($("#pageContent").empty(), points);
```

The point is that since the structure is recursive, it can nest to any depth, but the code is simpler.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e28r4/). This is quite a different approach, and Daniel Cook's answer is probably more immediately applicable to you current code, but I thought it worth to point out.

You could also extend it to add the "1", "1.1", "1.2" (and so on) numbers to the titles.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't think of recursive functions, yes, that would work very nicely.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to add the id to the created `li` if you store it to a variable.

The code below shows the basic concept. Does it make you more comfortable?

```
$.each(current.contents, function(_, mp){
    var $li = $('<li>' + mp.main + '</li>');       
    if (mp.subPoints.length){
        var $ul =$('<ul>')
        $.each(mp.subPoints, function(_, sp){
            $ul.append('<li>' + sp + '</li>');
        });
        $li.append($ul);
    }
    $pageContent.append($li);
});
```

Here's a [fiddle using the different coding](http://jsfiddle.net/4Lyu6/4/) I'm sure this could be improved more. I'm also still learning.

Comment: That is a helpful suggestion, thanks. Is it a best practice to have the index variable named the same when doing nested each loops like you have there (_ as the variable name) if you aren't going to use it?

Comment: I've been given the impression that using _ for a variable you do not intend to use is considered common practice at least. I got this impression from [this question with answers on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11406823/underscore-as-a-jquery-javascript-variable)

Comment: To answer the other part of your question, it hardly matters what the name of the index variable are since they are not used. If they were used, javascript would use the correct ones. Javascript handles scoping of variables on the function level, so even with a [name conflict](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope#Name_conflicts) the correct variable would be used. I didn't even think about the same name issue since the indexes aren't used.